# How to open a website with google chrome

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am making a desktop search app. I need a way to set the web browser target to Google Chrome.  I.e., if a person clicks a button in my app it will open Chrome with the website instead of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

run the chrome exe with a url as the first arg

`chrome.exe xkcd.com`

So something like...

`Process.Start("pathToChrome\\chrome.exe", "xkcd.com")`

Comment: +1, because this helped me at an important project. Wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: I would add that you should consider just Process.Start("http://xkcd.com") to open the website in the user's preferred browser, instead of mandating which browser they use (although as fair disclosure, Chrome is my own preferred browser).  If the company policy is to use Chrome, then you can make that a Windows Policy setting, and thus avoid the added dependency in case your application is run on a computer that doesn't have Chrome installed.